# Make class dynamic by using variable in between there name

Tags: php, dynamic-programming

Most of my classes in bundle are having same name. CRMFirstSecondExternal or CRMSecondThirdExternal and so on. Now I need to store the FirstSecond or SecondThird to a $variable and then use that $variable in between the class name to make it a proper call to that class.

```
use Escalon\Bundle\Admin\CRMBundle\Helper\CRMTravelExpenseExternal;
private function deletePreviousSchedule( $params )
{
    $queryParams = array();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if($params['bundleAndTableName'] == 'EscalonAdminCRMBundle:ClientServiceTe')
    {
        $helper = 'TravelExpense';
    }
    //$helper = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $helper);
    $crmEntityObject = new CRM.$helper.External;
    $crmEntityObject -> deletePreviousScheduleExternal($params);
}
```

Error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Escalon\Bundle\Admin\CRMBundle\Controller\CRM' not found in.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that class name is not concatenated correctly. Try this function

```
private function deletePreviousSchedule($params)
{
    $queryParams = array();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if($params['bundleAndTableName'] == 'EscalonAdminCRMBundle:ClientServiceTe')
    {
        $helper = 'Escalon\Bundle\Admin\CRMBundle\Helper\CRMTravelExpenseExternal';
    }

    $crmEntityObject = new $helper();
    $crmEntityObject->deletePreviousScheduleExternal($params);
}
```

You can find more documentation on this here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php

Also, it's possible to do

```
use Escalon\Bundle\Admin\CRMBundle\Helper\CRMTravelExpenseExternal;
private function deletePreviousSchedule($params)
{
    $queryParams = array();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if($params['bundleAndTableName'] == 'EscalonAdminCRMBundle:ClientServiceTe')
    {
        $helper = 'TravelExpense';
    }

    $className = "Escalon\Bundle\Admin\CRMBundle\Helper\CRM{$helper}External";
    $crmEntityObject = new $className();
    $crmEntityObject->deletePreviousScheduleExternal($params);
}
```

Comment: Hi friend thanks for the solution. Its working. But in my case I need to access other class as well depending on if condition. So I need a solution throw which I can concatenate the variable in between the class name as i has mentioned in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't use the first solution to access different classes depending on if conditions, but I added another solution. Also, you don't need the `use Escalon\Bundle\Admin\CRMBundle\Helper\CRMTravelExpenseExternal;` on the first line when you specify class with namespace.

Comment: I appreciate your help.